# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: selenium, rubymine

While running my simple selenium automation script on chrome broswer, i am getting below mentioned error. The script runs fine on firefox browser. Mine is HTTPS website.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9515
>   (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

IDE: Ruby Mine 7.1.4
Chrome Browser: 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit)

Script:

```
require "selenium/webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: manually open up a chrome browser, completely clear the cache, then try to access the target URL.  Do you get the same error?

Comment: No error is displayed when i open it manually. I have even re-installed chrome browser and ruby mine but no luck.

Comment: and what chromedriver version are you using

Comment: @sircapsalot using chrome driver v2.9 on port 9515

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had same problem as yours after Windows Update last time.
I updated chromedriver.exe from v2.9 to v2.24 and put it on bin directory where ruby installed, then it's fixed.

Comment: this is your exact problem @PankajSharma.  your chromedriver and chrome version need to be compatible.  chromedriver 2.9 is not compatible with the chrome version you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot athts and @sircapsalot . You guys rock.

Comment: This answer is amazing.